# Deriving the transformation law for the components of a vector using index notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, change-of-basis

I'm trying to derive the transformation law for the contravariant components of a vector $\mathbf{x}=x^i\mathbf e _i$ under a change of basis.

**My attempt**

If $\{\mathbf{\tilde e}_i \}$ is the new basis, we can express this vectors as a linear combination of the vectors of the old basis, so $\mathbf{\tilde e}_i=C^j_i\mathbf{ e}_j$. Any vector is invariant under a change of basis, so $\mathbf{x}=x^k\mathbf e _k=\tilde x^i\mathbf{\tilde e}_i=\tilde x^iC^j_i\mathbf{ e}_j$.

I know that I should get $x^j=\tilde x^iC^j_i$, so I'm tempted to identify $x^k$ with $\tilde x^iC^j_i$ taking $k=j$. But I don't think this is correct, since two sums can have the same value without having the same values for their addends... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The components of a vector decomposed with respect to a basis are unique. Follows from definition of a basis [(see wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)). In particular,

$$ \tilde{x_i} C_i^j  = P^j $$

Hence, $x= P^j e_j = x^j e_j$, equate the components/ coordinates with respect to basis.